# lwc PROJECT PATH ERROR Unknown

Tags: salesforcedx, lightning-web-components, vs-code

I'm working on some lwc, using SFDX and VS Code. About mid-day yesterday, I started getting an error when I tried to push to my scratch org. The push attempt took a long time -- like 2 min, and then it would give me an error:

```
PROJECT PATH    -     ERROR
________________ ______________
                   Unknown
```

Comment: You should in fact take off your findings from the post and add that as an answer so that it stands answered and is much more helpful for others.

Comment: If you could make an answer and accept it that would benefit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally discovered the issue: I had deleted everything from one of my lwc's CSS file. That was it. Just an empty file. I deleted the file and everything is back to normal.